# How do I custom sort legend items in AmCharts?

Tags: amcharts

Is there any easy way to custom sort the legend items instead of rewriting the dataset or creating a custom legend function?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bcJHw.png

I want them to show in this order

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cg9EF.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up looping through the data itself.

```
// new array for repopulating
var new_array = new Array();
// new key order
var new_order = ['Year', 'RENEWABLE POWER PLANTS', 'NUCLEAR POWER PLANTS', 'FOSSIL POWER PLANTS W/CCS', 'BIOFUELS', 'SYNTHETIC FUELS', 'VEHICLES', 'BUILDING TECHNOLOGIES', 'OTHER EFFICIENCY', 'OTHER', 'NATURAL GAS', 'COAL', 'PETROLEUM PRODUCTS', 'FOSSIL POWER PLANTS'];
// for each row in 'data'
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i += 1) {
  var new_data = {};
  // go through the 'new order' array
  for (z = 0; z < new_order.length; z += 1) {
    // re-order the keys in a new array
    new_data[new_order[z]] = data[i][new_order[z]];
  }
  // add the row to a new array
  new_array.push(new_data);
}
// replace data with the new array
data = new_array;
```